# PHP change variables from static function

Tags: php, class, oop, static

I have started to build this class, and I want to register a user:

```
<?php
class User {
    protected $_id;
    protected $_name;
    protected $_email;
    protected $_password;
    public $isLogged = false;
    public $errors = array();

    public function __construct() {

    }
    public static function register($username,$email,$password,$captcha,$agree) {
        $user = new self;
        array_push($user->errors,'Error!');
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
$user = User::register($_POST['username'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['password'],$captcha,$agree);
if(empty($user->errors)) {
    echo 'Success';
} else {
    echo 'Failed';
}
```

Why does it returns `Success`? I did `array_push`!

Comment: You didn't return anything in `register()`

Answer (score 3):

```
class User {

    // ...

    public static function register($username,$email,$password,$captcha,$agree) {
        $user = new self;
        array_push($user->errors,'Error!');
        return $user;
    }
}
```

You forgot to return the `$user` object from `register()`.